# jQuery: How to check multiple elements with .on event

Tags: jquery, class, jquery-selectors

Is it possible to check more than one element **with** the .on event?
If so, how?

```
$(document).on('click', ('class-1', 'class-2', 'class-3'), function ()
{
  ...
});
```

The code above shows my try so far. This works fine for the 'class-3' but the others are ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can do it using the jquery [**multiple selector**](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/), like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.class-1, .class-2, .class-3', function ()
{
```

Comment: Really? That simple? Oh man ... And thanks for the link. It works well